# Determine Person from the Camera

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I need some help for finding the person with Camera.

is it possible to fetch person from the groups if he has install applicator in that device from the camera?

the basic concept is when user rotate camera to any person camera will fetch image of that user and will search it and compare it with application database for if that user is register in application or not and display his information.

if its possible and you have some reference then please share with me.

Thank you for read question.

Answer (score 7):

Core Image has a new [CIFaceFeature](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIFaceFeature/Reference/Reference.html) to recognize faces in real time; you can start with these examples to take an overview:
[SquareCam](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html) (from Apple)
[iOS Facial Recognition](http://i.ndigo.com.br/2012/01/ios-facial-recognition/)
[Easy Face detection with Core Image](http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5/)
Then you have to design the logic to compare and store images.

Comment: Hello Mat Thanx For the answer. but its recognizing face from the image but i need camera will fetch image of that user and will search it and compare it with application database for if that user is register in application or not and display his information.

Comment: try looking for open source face recognition projects... like libFace. But I don't know how reliable they work, just try it.

Comment: @Smith try read the last three lines of the description of the first link (SquareCam): "integrating with CoreImages'new CIFaceDetector to find face in real time VideoDataOutput, as well as in a captured still image".

Comment: @Smith You're welcome, your question is good as first question on SO, please consider to accept the answers you receive from other users in order to receive answers again :)