# How to recognize, Human Face from an Image(s) in iPhone/Ipad?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, image-recognition, face-recognition

I want to create an app ,that will recognize human face , if there is no Face detected then it will return proper message.

Is there any Framework OR Class with used of we recognize Face from an images

[image]

[image]

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10647756/251513) answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this from ios 5 api, here is sample code you can download it 
http://maniacdev.com/FaceDetectionExample.zip

Answer (score 4):

Please check code from [here](http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5/). I think It will help you.

Answer (score 3):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) does seem to have a [Face Recognition API](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceRecognition). You can find more information [here](http://code.google.com/p/ios-face-detection/).

Answer (score 3):

Try [CIDetector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) and Google it find more details. It's Apple's framework, works fine!